# Meaning of term "Irregularly resigned" for ancestor who served in American Revolutionary War?

Tags: united-states, military-records

While researching an ancestor who served during the American Revolutionary War, I found the term "irregularly resigned" being used.  The term, as far as I can see, is only being used when referring to an officer's commission.

Any idea what this phrase means?

The context of the question is from "Documents of the Senate of the State of New York, Annual Report of the State Historian".  The actual quote is dated 1798 and reads, "Brigadier General Othniel Taylor having (irregularly) resigned, his resignation is accepted."  I believe it relates to his State Militia rank and service even though he was in the American Revolutionary War.

Comment: Welcome to the site, user291. This is a nice question, but adding some context will help make it a great question. Please add details about which revolution (for example, this might be the American Revolutionary war). It would help to know the specifics about the document in which you found the term, "irregularly resigned"; this would probably include identifying the name and service of the ancestor you are researching.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to add this comment to my question, @GeneJ.  Too much work and not enough play!  The context of the question is from "Documents of the Senate of the State of New York, Annual Report of the State Historian".  The actual quote is dated 1798 and reads, "Brigadier General Othniel Taylor having (irregularly) resigned, his resignation is accepted."  I believe it relates to his State Militia rank and service even though he was in the American Revolutionary War.

Comment: Thanks! How about one of us edit the question and add that additional context. (Yes--we can edit questions on StackExchange!)

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that an "irregular resignation" refers to any demand linking continued service to some other condition. An example might be "If my men don't receive better equipment, then I will have to consider my position" which can be construed as a threat to resign and accepted as such.

I regret that I can not give a source for the following example

> *... and among other things, praying the restoration of John Wiliams to the command of the brigade, and arrainging the conduct of the late Council, and requesting, if the prayer of their petition could not be granted, that they might be gratified in accompanying their brother officers in their removal from military services – whereupon, Resolved, that the request of said Peter P. French, John West, David Carswell, Casparus Baine and John Beatty be granted, and that their said petition be considered as an irregular resignation and as such be accepted accordingly.*